# If statements on negative decimal values ranges

Tags: c#

I am quite new to C# and I want to do an if condition on a number range of a negative value e.g if(percentage is equals to -60  to -80 ) then DoWork, my question is , How do I check using an if statement, as switches doesn't allow checks on decimal values. -60 to -80 means (negative 61 up till negative 81) as my condition, how can I achieve this in C#, any help will be greatly appreciated ,like I said I am still new to the .Net world.

Comment: Did you mean negative 61 up till negative 79?

Comment: if (a <= -60 && a => -80) { DoWork; }

Comment: `Papi` this should make for some good reading in your spare time 
[C# Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(value >= -80 && value <= -60) {
  doWork();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing when you say 'decimal value ranges' and percentages, you're doing the calculation, so in that case:

`if( x >= -.81 && x <= -.61)
{
//do something
}`

otherwise, it would be:

`if( x >= -81 && x <= -61)
{
//do something
}`

Comment: where did the extra 1 come from?  why not .0001?  <= and >= are your friend

Comment: the extra 1 came from this portion of OP's question: `-60 to -80 means (negative 61 up till negative 81) as my condition` but you're right, it should be `<=` and `>=` instead, I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

```
if(number >= -80.0f && number <= -60.0f)
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: -80 is less than -60 so the numbers are backwards here

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a >= -80 && a <= -60) {
  DoWork();
}
```